# Update in mongodb, more than one way?

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to add a "role" to a document, which is an update command such as this:

```
db.users.update({username: 'someUser'},{'$set': {roles: ['user', 'admin']}});
```

To a document structured like this:

```
{
  _id:'22222',
  username : '',
  roles: ['user']
}
```

Is there any other way of doing this except from the query above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are also [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) that adds to set and [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) that removes from set operators.

So your query may look like:

```
db.users.update(
  { username: 'someUser' },
  { $addToSet: { roles: 'admin' } }
);
```

**UPD:** As @Juan Carlos Farah mentioned there is also [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) that appends value to array operator.

Comment: I specified $pull to show how the element can be removed as well.

Comment: I see. You might want to specify that `$pull` removes, as the question asks specifically for an insertion into the array.